# Enumerator with hidden options

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an excel document generator project. Currently i'm working on cell styles part.

So i have next structure:

```
public class Styles : List<Style>, ISerializableClass
{
    ...some special methods...
}
```

The thing i want to achieve:

When some Style ( item ) is being added to the Styles i want to automatically add/modify/update the Style id.

In other words i want to override the base list.Add() behavior. **How can i achieve this?**

Or i just should add this method in my Styles class:

```
public void Add(Style style)
    {
        /*
         * Some mu logic
        */
        base.Add(style);
    }
```

**To hide the default List.Add() method?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to implement `IList<T>` yourself instead of inheriting from `List<T>`. You can then delegate most of the implementation to a `List<T>` field:

```
public class Styles : IList<Style>, ISerializableClass
{
    private List<Style> _list = new List<Style>();

    public void Add(Style style)
    {
        // Your stuff here
        _list.Add(style);
    }

    // ...
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/3764814) for more details about why inheriting from `List<T>` is not a good idea.

And you should *almost always* avoid hiding base class methods. Because this is easily defeated with code such as:

```
var stylesList = new Styles(); // Suppose this hides List<T>.Add
var castedList = (IList<Styles>)stylesList;
castedList.Add(new Style()); // <-- this still calls List<T>.Add
```

IMHO, the only *acceptable* use case for method hiding is in situations like `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` hiding `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` where both methods do exactly the same thing anyway.

Comment: Aha... Thanks, both your suggestion and a link gave me a good amount of info to think about. You helped me.